Android: Spotify API preview_url for tracks is suddenly being returned as null
I'm using the Spotify API copyright free 30 sec preview of songs in my app, and suddenly it stopped working and all tracks returned have a null preview_url.
I tried specifying different markets -like "US" and "ES"- in the query to no avail, the exact same occurs.
The most weird thing is that it was working perfectly until now, it stopped working some days ago, so everything points to a Spotify issue/new restriction.
Below is my Kotlin code to get a track:
fun getTrack(token: String?, spotifyIdTrack: String?, market: String) {
    val api = SpotifyApi()
    var accessToken = ""
    val objJSON = awJson.str2JSON(token)
    if (objJSON != null) {
        try {
            accessToken =
                if (objJSON.has("access_token")) objJSON.getString("access_token") else ""
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            // TODO: log?
        }
        if (accessToken.isNotEmpty()) {
            api.setAccessToken(accessToken)
            val spotify = api.service

            // Use MutableMap<String, Any> for the query parameters
            val queryMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
            queryMap["market"] = market

            spotify.getTrack(spotifyIdTrack, queryMap, object : Callback<Track?> {
                override fun success(track: Track?, response: Response) {
                    listener!!.onTrackGet(track)
                }

                override fun failure(error: RetrofitError) {
                    // TODO: log?
                }
            })
        } else {
            // TODO: log?
        }
    }
}

This is frustrating, because it ruins the user experience in my app.
Of course I checked similar SO and GitHub posts and threads, but no one has a satisfactory response to my issue.
I checked the "available_markets" field for many of the responses and it is also being returned as null, what gives sense to the fact preview_url is null, but what I also think it's not normal, considering it was working.
Anything else I can try?

This is an ugly workaround, but now I definitely know we won't find a better solution (because this is how the Spotify API currently works):
Spotify includes the preview_url in the embed data in the html of the track page. This means that if you get the html for the page there will be one script containing a json with all track information, including an "audioPreview" node.
I'm fetching the html for the track url (using the id and the following code) and then I use JsonPath library from jayway to get the audioPreview  node value.
fun fetchPreviewUrl(trackId: String): String? {
    val embedUrl = "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/$trackId"
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(embedUrl)
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        if (!response.isSuccessful) {
            println("Failed to fetch embed page: ${response.code}")
            return null
        }

        val html = response.body?.string() ?: return null
        val document = Jsoup.parse(html)
        val scriptElements = document.getElementsByTag("script")

        for (element in scriptElements) {
            val scriptContent = element.html()
            if (scriptContent.isNotEmpty()){
                /*val jsonObject = JSONObject(scriptContent)
                val audioPreview1 = findNodeValue1(jsonObject, "audioPreview")*/
                return findNodeValueWithJsonPath(scriptContent, "audioPreview")
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}

private fun findNodeValueWithJsonPath(jsonString: String, targetNode: String): String? {
    return try {
        // Construct the JsonPath query
        val query = "$..$targetNode.url"
        println("Using JsonPath Query: $query") // Debug query

        // Perform the query
        // Handle cases where the result is a list (e.g., multiple matches)
        when (val result = JsonPath.read<Any>(jsonString, query)) {
            is List<*> -> {
                if (result.isNotEmpty()) result[0].toString() else null // Return the first match
            }
            is String -> result // Directly return the string if it's not a list
            else -> null
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Error: ${e.message}")
        null
    }
}

And this is the implementation needed for gradle:
implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.8.0'

This way you will get the audioPreview that you can use the exact way as the preview_url, but this is very ugly.
I'll use it to get by until I'm ready to replace Spotify.

This is not exactly an answer, but the closest to it.
As far as I've been reading, the best way for the preview_url not to be null is to use Authorization flow instead of User Credentials (the one I'm currently using with a token), but the problem is that method forces a user to authenticate with Spotify from within your app, and this is horrible from a user experience perspective, in fact I won't go that way.
Other possibilities are forget about Spotify and switch to Deezer or iTunes, they both have 30 sec previews and no restrictions to get a preview_url, but it's very confusing why it was working until now, and of course it's frustrating to suddenly be in the need to replace a lot of code in you already working app.

Maybe your problem is related to the fact that they deprecated several API endpoints https://developer.spotify.com/blog/2024-11-27-changes-to-the-web-api including 30-second preview URLs

Well, hadn't checked that, thanks for pointing that out. What it says is that preview_url can be null, NOT that it will be always null. It also says "Audio Preview Clips may not be offered as a standalone service or product.", don't know how to interpret this. It's clear something has changed in the api, unfortunately, but don't know if there is any solution / workaround to this.

I've read in some GitHub threads that there is a workaround for this known issue @jose-vicente, but was not able to find it. Do you have any idea about that?

I encountered the same issue, and I used a similar technique to extract the previewUrl from a playlist embed. Here's how I did it:
const fetchPlaylistData = async (playlistId) => {
  try {
    // Fetch the playlist embed page HTML content
    const htmlContent = await fetch(`https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/${playlistId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then(res => res.text());

    // Regex to extract the JSON data from the <script> tag with id "__NEXT_DATA__"
    const regex = /<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application\/json">(.+?)<\/script>/s;
    const match = htmlContent.match(regex);

    if (match) {
      // Parse the JSON data from the matched content
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(match[1]);

      // Check if the track list exists and contains items with audio previews
      if (jsonData?.props?.pageProps?.state?.data?.entity?.trackList) {
        // Filter tracks that have an audio preview
        return jsonData.props.pageProps.state.data.entity.trackList.filter(item => item.audioPreview != null);
      } else {
        console.log("No track list found or no audio preview available.");
        return [];
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No JSON data found in the page.");
      return [];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching playlist data:", error);
    return [];
  }
};

// Example usage
fetchPlaylistData('2VfS335RjpEaDQyFpktfKS').then(tracks => {
  console.log('Tracks with audio previews:', tracks);
});


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
